# Can I not compile Qt graphics code without Qt moc compiler?

Tags: qt4

I have a requirement where I have a bunch GUI programs (games etc) that are intended to run wherever (meaning any OS) the Qt library is available i.e. the programs should run just fine on say Windows, Linux etc.

So I am planning to write an interface that the programs can use if they want something drawn. This interface will be common across operating systems and will have Qt Graphics APIs i.e. QPainter to draw stuff.

My concern is that I would need the Qt moc compiler because I will be using Q_OBJECT in my interface code. I would like the programs to compile with gcc and not require anything extra. Of course, I will need the Qt libraries to build.

Thanks,
Krishna

Answer (score 0):

From what i know MOC is required to compile Qt Code since Q_OBJECT and  other Qt Macros are used throughout the code , and since MOC is needed to generate Meta-Objects.